# Does NSSplitView autosavename work?

Tags: objective-c, nssplitview

I can't seem to get NSSplitView autosave to work - can anyone confirm that by adding an autosavename in IB it should work ?  I am using auto layout but my splitView is not remembering the position of the divider.

EDIT
I would expect the position of the divider to be remembered between application restarts.  All I see is the divider position always starting at the default position that was set originally in IB.

Comment: What are you seeing or expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Well strangely enough this now seems to be working!  So I guess I can answer my own question - YES setting an autosave name in IB should result in the SplitView remembering the divider position between application launches.

No idea when it started working or why it was not working for a while.  My bad no doubt.

FYI I am using a subclassed NSSplitView with autolayout. One thing I have changed is I load the right views at runtime now.  Anyway for those struggling with splitViews, they can be made to work with some fiddling it seems.